# Select all records between two timestamps and then group by the number of occurrences of a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database table called incidents. In this table I have the following columns

```
index | timestamp | email
```

I want to select the number of occurances each e-mail address appears between two timestamps.

So far I can do this:

```
 "SELECT `email`, count(*) FROM `incidents` GROUP BY `email` ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

The above query works and gives me a list of all the unique e-mail addresses ordered by the count of how many times they appear. However it doesn't take account of the timestamp.

Ideally I want to do something like the following in one query:

```
SELECT `email`, `timestamp` FROM `incidents` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 23:59:59';

COUNT(*) GROUP BY `email` ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

This would select all the reccords between the two timestamps and then count the number of times each e-mail address appears and order by this count. How can I achieve this in one query?

Comment: SELECT count(*) as cnt,email,timestamp FROM `incidents` where timestamp between '2015-12-24 12:00:00' and '2015-12-24 12:30:00' group by email ORDER BY cnt DESC

Comment: Assuming the same timestamp applies to all emails, you should be able to do this just by adding the WHERE criteria to your original query, like so: `SELECT email, count(*) FROM incidents WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 23:59:59' GROUP BY email ORDER BY count(*) DESC;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would there be anything wrong with simply adding a `WHERE` clause to your first query?

```
SELECT `email`, COUNT(*)
FROM `incidents`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `email`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Thanks for setting up a Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I think I had all the key ingredients but just couldn't put them together.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. Here's one with a sub-query:

```
SELECT A.email,
COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT *
  FROM incidents
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 23:59:59'
  ) A
GROUP BY A.email
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

This may not be the most efficient way to do it though depending on the size of the table.